# Horizontal and Vertical filter in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

Hey guys I'm trying to achieve the above, and having trouble finding a starting point (Also apologies on using an image, I'm fairly new to both stack overflow and access so I couldn't format a nice table for an example).

Here's the table structure:

[image]

Essentially I want to build a query/filter that will have to select the Month (Horizontal selection) (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc), then let you select the Term, and finally the last selection should only contain that price that corresponds to the Month and Term selected.

I would appreciate if someone could point me in a direction to achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

why you have column for month, if you can't change this structure you must create union and then condition to month, for example:

```
select * from (
select customer_name, Term, 1 as month, 1stMonth as data from table 
union select customer_name, Term, 2 as month, 2stMonth as data from table)
where term = 1 and month = 2
```

if you rebuild your table to have month as field with value of month, you can create crossview on it, to look like your existing table

Comment: The structure is like that because this data is actually something I don't have much control over. It's been setup like that by someone else in the organization and I'm building a database that can "play nice" with the data presented. This table is essentially used to create a price matrix for an external user to use. But thank's for the suggestion, once I get back to the office I'll give that a try